# wait till lateinit is assigned

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple class which I use for dependency injection:

```
class ViewModelFactory( application: Application ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory
{

    val mainFlow                  = MainFlow()
    private val authorizationFlow = AuthorizationFlow()

    init
    {
        mainFlow.authFlow = authorizationFlow
    }

    ..
}
```

The main flow class:

```
class MainFlow
{
    lateinit var authFlow : AuthorizationFlow

    init
    {
        if( ::authFlow.isInitialized )
            authFlow.start()
    }
}
```

And the authorization flow

```
class AuthorizationFlow
{
    fun start()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

The obvious problem is that the authFlow property within the MainFlow class is never initialized when the *init* gets executed. How can I "wait" for the authFlow to become initialized and only then call the authFlow.start() method? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a member injection instead of making it a lateinit

```
class MainFlow {
    var authFlow : AuthorizationFlow? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            value?.start()
        }
}
```

The downside is now you are dealing with a nullable type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Delegates.observable`:

```
var authFlow: AuthorizationFlow? by Delegates.observable<AuthorizationFlow?>(null) { _, old, new -> {
    if (old == null && new != null) {
        new.start()
    }
}
```

and remove your `init` block.